# Getting exception when scnario is failed in cucumber

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber

Requirement- I have cucumber Framework and I want to capture exception and send it by email

Solution:- I have written a method in after function to send email if scenario is failed, I am able to capture screen shot and send

My Question. Is there anyway to get exception logs in after scenario.
The cucumber report correctly prints log but how do i get programmatically

Solution 2.. While debugging  I can view the error in scenario.stepResults()..but I cant use this function in after function. is there way to get data from scenario.stepResults?

any solution.

Answer (score 0):

This problem may arise because you might have old version of cucumber, because this was a bug in older build.
Also try **scenario.exception.message** in after method, This should work.

Comment: .exception.message is not available. I am using 1.2.5 cucumber i feel this is latest . only following  functions are available                                                                   
 void embed(byte[] data, String mimeType)
Embeds data into the report(s).
String getId() 
String getName() 
Collection<String> getSourceTagNames() 
String getStatus() 
boolean isFailed() 
void write(String text) .   Do you think I am missing something.<dependencies>

Comment: I think latest version of cucumber is 3.1.2.
Check link https://rubygems.org/gems/cucumber/versions

Comment: Check for latest in io.cucumber in maven for java

Comment: using https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-java the latest version is 1.2.5. If I try to use https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-junit/3.0.2 I get exception cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: cucumber.runtime.java.JavaBackend.<in I am using these  <artifactId>cucumberjava</artifactId<version>1.2.5</version> 
 <artifactId>cucumber-jvm</artifactId> <version>1.2.5</version <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>  <version>1.2.5</version> <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-deps</artifactId> <version>1.0.5</version>